# How scala inferred types in this code examples?

Tags: scala

Hi I am new to Scala and programming in general. I took a Scala course on coursera one of the assignments was to create functions that take sets as parameters and return another set which is a union/intersection/difference of the 2 sets. Here is the solution for intersection:

```
def intersect(s: Set, t: Set): Set = elem => s(elem) && t(elem)
```

I don't understand the elem. How does Scala know it is an element of the set and why if tried in shell it returns error: missing a parameter type.

The solutions for union and difference (same):

```
def union(s: Set, t: Set): Set = elem => s(elem) || t(elem)

def diff(s: Set, t: Set): Set = elem => s(elem) && !t(elem)
```

From [Scala Set](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Set):

A generic trait for mutable sets.

A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements.

Implementation note: This trait provides most of the operations of a Set independently of its representation. It is typically inherited by concrete implementations of sets.

To implement a concrete set, you need to provide implementations of the following methods:

```
def contains(key: A): Boolean
def iterator: Iterator[A]
def +(elem: A): This
def -(elem: A): This
```

Comment: Look closely at the definition of `Set` and you should be able to figure out what `elem` is. Also, you should post the definition of `Set` if you want an answer (I just know it because I took the same class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From last year's scala class on coursera:

```
object FunSets {
  /**
   * We represent a set by its characteristic function, i.e.
   * its `contains` predicate.
   */
  type Set = Int => Boolean
  // [...]
}
```

I.e. `Set` does not refer to a predefined scala trait, but to a function that takes an `Int` as a parameter and returns a `Boolean`. E.g. a set that contains a single element `{3}` is represented by a function `f(Int)` where `f(3)` returns true and `f(x)` with `x != 3` returns false.

The example you gave:

```
def intersect(s: Set, t: Set): Set = elem => s(elem) && t(elem)
```

only works if you have defined the type `Set` as `Int => Boolean` before.

Answer (score 0):

A parallel can be drawn with a filter function:

```
List(1,2,4,5).filter(elem => elem < 4) = List(1, 2)
```

What happens here is the same. We define a variable "elem" and define it by its constraint that s(elem) && t(elem) for union.

As for why it doesn't work in commandline, I believe that a "type" is defined for Set instead of it being a normal Set. Look in the code